# Closing Jframe after a file is selected in JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener, jfilechooser

I want to make it so that my JFrame closes after a file is selected in JFileChooser. How should I do this? I tried using the dispose(); function but it doesn't apply to the actionPerformed listener. Any tips?

```
    public static void createWindow() {

    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("JComboBox Test");
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JButton inbutton = new JButton("Select Input File");
    inbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
          Test method = new Test();
          File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
          String outFile = selectedFile.getParent() + "/baseball_out.txt";
          String inFile = selectedFile.getPath();
          method.baseballedit(inFile, outFile);
          //ADD CLOSING ACTION HERE//
        }
      }
    });
    frame.add(inbutton);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

Comment: `frame.dispose()` should work. how exactly did you try using `dispose()`?

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 1):

> I tried using the dispose(); function but it doesn't apply to the actionPerformed listener.

`dispose` needs to be invoked on the `JFrame` rather than on the `ActionListener`. Make `frame` `final` and you can then call

```
frame.dispose();
```